# How do I combine multiple http requests and merge results

Tags: http, rxjs

I need to handle a situation where I have 3 endpoints to call and would like to get the data in the most convenient/efficient way. The first call can be handled independently and returns a single result. The second endpoint returns a collection but will need to initiate 0-* subsequent calls, where a given key is present.

Ideally would like to receive the collection (from the 2nd endpoint call) as a mutated/new collection that includes the result from the 3rd endpoint call.

I am currently using forkJoin(observableA$, observableB$) to handle the first 2 calls in parallel but I cannot work out how to include the sequential calls and have the data included in observableB$

```
//Customer observable
const customer$ = this._customerManagementService.getCustomer(
  accountNumber
);
```

```
 return forkJoin({
      customer: customer$,
      saleCycles: saleCyclesWithVehicle$
    }).pipe(finalize(() => this._loaderFactoryService.hide()));
```

```
 getSalesWithVehicle(accountNumber: string, dealerKey: string) {
    return this._salesCycleService
      .getCyclesForCustomer({
        customerNumber: accountNumber,
        dealerKey: dealerKey
      })
      .pipe(
        concatMap((results: ISaleCycle[]) => {
          return results.map(cycle => {
            return this._purchaseVehicleService.getPurchaseVehicle(
              cycle.vehicleKey
            );
          });
        })
      );
  }
```

I expect the collection to include further data as a new property on the original collection

***UPDATE***

After a bit more thought maybe I should be using reduce somewhere in the solution. This way I can be in control of what's getting push into the array and it could be dynamic?

```
  getSalesWithVehicle(accountNumber: string, dealerKey: string) {
    return this._salesCycleService
      .getCyclesForCustomer({
        customerNumber: accountNumber,
        dealerKey: dealerKey
      })
      .pipe(
        switchMap((results: ISaleCycle[]) => {
          return results.map(cycle => {
            if (cycle.vehicleKey) {
              return this._purchaseVehicleService
                .getPurchaseVehicle(cycle.vehicleKey)
                .pipe(
                  reduce((acc, vehicle) => {
                    return { cycle: cycle, vehicle: vehicle };
                  }, []),
                  toArray()
                );
            }
            else {
              ///No extra data to be had
            }
          });
        }),
        concatAll()
      );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `concatMap()` to merge the responses of HTTP requests 2 and 3.

```
import { of } from 'rxjs'; 
import { map, concatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const pretendGetCustomer = of({accountNumber: 123, name:"John Doe"});

const pretendGetVehiculeHttpRequest = (customerNumber) => {
  return of([{custNum: 123, vehicleId:"2"}, {custNum: 123, vehicleId:"1"}]);
}
const pretendGetCyclesHttpRequest = (cycleIds) => {
  return of([{id:"1", name:"yellow bike", retailPrice:"$10"}, {id:"2", name:"red bike", retailPrice:"$20"}]);
}

const yourFunction = () => {
  pretendGetCustomer.subscribe(customer => {
    // Assuming you do other things here with cust, reason why we are subscribing to this separately
    // isHappy(customer)

    // Your second & third calls
    pretendGetVehiculeHttpRequest(customer.accountNumber).pipe(
      // Need to use concatMap() to subscribe to new stream
      // Note: use mergeMap() if you don't need the 1st stream to be completed
      //       before calling the rest
      concatMap(purchases => {
        const cyclesIds = purchases.map(p => p.vehicleId);
        // concatMap() requires an Observable in return
        return pretendGetCyclesHttpRequest(cyclesIds).pipe(
          // Use map() here because we just need to use the data,
          // don't need to subscribe to another stream
          map(cycles=>{
            // Retrun whatever object you need in your subscription
            return {
              customerNumber: customer.accountNumber,
              customerName: customer.name,
              purchases: purchases.map(p => cycles.find(c => p.vehicleId === c.id))
            }
          })
        );
      })
    ).subscribe(resultof2and3 => {
      // Do something with the new/mutated Object which is a result of
      // your HTTP calls #2 and #3
      console.log(resultof2and3);
    });
  });
}

yourFunction();
```

I made a stackblitz if you want to see the above run (see console): https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-nqi7f1

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I eventually came up with. I've taken the advice from BoDeX and used concatMap(). In my mind it was clear that I wanted to use forkJoin and be able to reference the results by object key, I.e customer or saleCycles.

In the scenario where a vehicleKey was present I needed to return the results in a defined data structure, using map(). Likewise, if no vehicle was found then I just needed the outer observable.

```
const customer$ = this._customerManagementService.getCustomer(accountNumber);

const saleCyclesWithVehicle$ = this.getSalesWithVehicle(accountNumber,dealerKey);

getSalesWithVehicle(accountNumber: string, dealerKey: string) {
    return this._salesCycleService
      .getCyclesForCustomer({
        customerNumber: accountNumber,
        dealerKey: dealerKey
      })
      .pipe(
        concatMap(cycles => {
          return from(cycles).pipe(
            concatMap((cycle: ISaleCycle) => {
              if (cycle.vehicleKey) {
                return this._purchaseVehicleService
                  .getPurchaseVehicle(cycle.vehicleKey)
                  .pipe(
                    map(vehicle => {
                      return { cycle: cycle, vehicle: vehicle };
                    })
                  );
              } else {
                return of({ cycle: cycle });
              }
            }),
            toArray()
          );
        })
      );
  }

return forkJoin({
      customer: customer$,
      saleCycles: saleCyclesWithVehicle$
    }).pipe(finalize(() => this._loaderFactoryService.hide()));
```